# LYX - Subject index with makeindex

Tags: lyx, koma-script, makeindex

I am writing a book in german with almost 400 pages using LYX in KOMA-Script. On recommendation, I should use the index processor Makeindex for this (so far I have used texindy).
I wrote this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[makeidx]
\makeindex[-g]
```

In the document settings I tried makeindex or standard.
I wrote in the toll settings at output LATEX user defined or makeindex.

I have tried all combinations of the above entries. However, no index is given to me in the PDF file. What am I doing wrong? I scoured Google intensively. I've searched through a number of manuals, guides and tutorials. Most of the clues concern LateX. They are interesting, but not useful to me because - as I said - I use LYX. And the LYX-relevant documents did not contain anything helpful to me.

I would like to show you the status of my work and send you the corresponding LYX, TEX and PDF files. Unfortunately, I can't find any functions for it ...

Some data about my work environment:

```
OS
Edition: Windows 10 Home
Version: 21H1
Installed on: 11.‎03.‎2021
OS build: 19043.1237
Services: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
 
LYX
LyX 2.3.6.1 (2020-12-29)
CMake Build

System directory: C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3\Resources\
User directory: ~\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3\
Qt-Version (Laufzeit): 5.15.2
Qt-Version (bei Erstellung): 5.15.2
```

PLEASE can you help me?

TeX code:

```
\batchmode 
\makeatletter 
\def\input@path{{"C:/Users/aplih/Documents/Eigene Daten/Andreas/Denke/Buecher/02 - Umsonst-nicht-aber-vergeblich/99-Fehlersuche/Index/Makeindex/MWE3/"}} 
\makeatother 
\documentclass[10pt,naustrian,most,usenames,dvipsnames]{scrbook} \usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine} 
\usepackage[c5paper]{geometry} \geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.7cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2.5cm} 
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex

\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[xetex,unicode=true,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false, breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false] {hyperref} 
\makeatletter 
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth} % auxiliary length 
\usepackage[indentunit=1em,hangindent=1em,subsubindent=1em]{idxlayout} 
\usepackage[makeidx] 
\makeindex[-g] 
\AtBeginDocument{ \def\labelitemi{\a)} } 
\makeatother 
\usepackage{polyglossia} \setdefaultlanguage[variant=austrian,spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document} 
Text\index{Text} 
\printindex 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue (I do not know Lyx, but I know you can create the resulting TeX code with it)?

Comment: Of course LYX creates a TEX file. But I don't know how to publish this HERE. When I copy the content of the TEX file here into the answer box, I get the message that "Too long by 3000 characters". What can I do to show you my TEX file?

Comment: Simply make it shorter, we do not need the complete document, only a part still resulting in your issue ...